# Nest TableLayout inside LinearLayout - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I want to produce an Android screen layout that looks something like the following:

```
Label   Text Field
Label   Text Field
Label   Text Field

-----Button-------
-----TextField----
```

That is, I want to have a TableLayout at the top, with a number of items underneath the table layout (mainly so I can force these items to be at the bottom of the screen). I have tried to nest them as in the code below, but the items at the bottom don't seem to appear.

Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Latitude:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:text="Not available"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Longitude:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/longitude"
        android:text="Not available"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Altitude:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/altitude"
        android:text="Not available"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Accuracy:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/accuracy"
        android:text="Not available"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"/>
<TextView android:text="Test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your table layout add these

```
android:layout_height="80dp"  
 android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

also for the bottom button and and text view add fixed height.If your table needs more space
then put it between scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Set the weight of the table to "1", and the height to "0dp".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow>
...
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For textfield you have to use EditText in place of TextView and add `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` to each widget used in your application.